# Drawing a Sphere and ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I want to draw a sphere and a parametric curve, but the output doesn't show the parametric curve.

> ```
> Show[{
>   Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r /. r -> 200], Axes -> True], 
>   ParametricPlot3D[{a (1 - e^2)/(1 + Cos[u])*Cos[u], 
>     a (1 - e^2)/(1 + Cos[u])*Sin[u], 0 /. {a -> 1000, e -> 0}}, {u, 0,
>      Pi/2}]
>   }, PlotRange -> 1000]
> ```

Here's the output:
[image]

How do i fix this?

Comment: `Show[{Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r /. r -> 200], Axes -> True], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{a (1 - e^2)/(1 + Cos[u])*Cos[u], 
     a (1 - e^2)/(1 + Cos[u])*Sin[u], 0} /. {a -> 1000, e -> 0}, {u, 
    0, Pi/2}]}, PlotRange -> 1000]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo in where you replaced the values for a and e. The replacement should be at the end of the list in ParametricPlot3D.

```
Show[{Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r /. r -> 200], Axes -> True], ParametricPlot3D[{a (1 - e^2)/(1 + Cos[u])*Cos[u], a (1 - e^2)/(1 + Cos[u])*Sin[u], 0} /. {a -> 1000, e -> 0}, {u, 0, Pi/2}]}, PlotRange -> 1000]
```